# Razor page: complex modeling binding not updating model

Tags: asp.net-core, binding, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, model-binding

So I'm trying to create a little tool where a user can select a set of days. I however need quite a complex model for extra data.

```
public class DayRange{
    ...
    List<DaySelected> Days
    ...
}
   
public class DaySelected{
    public bool Selected{ get; set;}
    public string DayName {get; set;}
    public DaySelected(string Day){
        Selected = false;
        DayName = day;
    }
}
```

My Razorpage looks like this:

```
@Model DayRange
...
<form asp-action="RegisterSelection" asp-controller="DayRegister">
<table>
@foreach (var Day in Model.Days)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input asp-for=@Day.Selected />
        </td>                                                            
    </tr>
}
</table>
<button type="submit">Confirm</button>

</form>
```

My method Registerselection looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RegisterSelection(DayRange dr){
    ...
}
```

However, whenever I change any of textboxes, all of the selected bool values remain the same. Can anybody help me on my way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo to pass data to action correctly:

Model:

```
public class DayRange
    {
        public List<DaySelected> Days { get; set; }
    }

    public class DaySelected
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public string DayName { get; set; }
        public DaySelected()
        {
           
        }
        public DaySelected(string Day)
        {
            Selected = false;
            DayName = Day;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@Model DayRange
<form asp-action="RegisterSelection" asp-controller="DayRegister">
    <table>
        @{ var i = 0;}
        @foreach (var Day in Model.Days)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for=@Day.Selected name="Days[@i].Selected" />
                    @Day.DayName
                    <input asp-for=@Day.DayName name="Days[@i].DayName" hidden />
                </td>
            </tr>
            i ++;
        }
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Confirm</button>

</form>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the demo! I was able to make it work now, so I've accepted your answer as the solution for this issue. I'm simply wondering, was the reason that it didn't work simply because I didn't fill in the name of the components of the checkboxes?  My apologies for the simple question, this is mostly new to me.

Comment: Yes,.net core bind data with name attribute.